# Switch video source Agora.io

Tags: arkit, agora.io, sceneview

My agora app has a custom video source as ARView that I transfer using [ARVideoKit](https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit). How can I implement switching to the front camera?

My initial idea was just to set local video, but it does nothing

```
@objc private func switchCamera() {
    captureType = captureType == .ar ? .camera : .ar
    setCaptureType(to: captureType)
}

private func stopScene(){
    arRecorder.rest()
    sceneView.session.pause()
}

private func startScene() {        
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    arRecorder.prepare(configuration)
}

private func setCaptureType(to type: CaptureType) {
switch type {
case .ar:
    startScene()
    agoraKit.disableVideo()
    agoraKit.setVideoSource(arVideoSource)
    
case .camera:
    stopScene()
    
    agoraKit.enableVideo()
    agoraKit.setVideoSource(nil)
    let videoCanvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
    videoCanvas.uid = 0
    videoCanvas.renderMode = .hidden
    videoCanvas.view = localVideoView
    agoraKit.setupLocalVideo(videoCanvas)
}}
```

Basically, I need to stop ARSession, probably remove the custom video source and set local video as input.

To set ARView as a video source I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/agora-io/how-to-build-an-augmented-reality-remote-assistance-app-c1c464d1c9a6)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to switch the camera source for Agora, instead you should update the ARKit config to use the front camera

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, RenderARDelegate, RecordARDelegate {
  weak var cameraFlipBtn : UIButton!
  enum cameraFacing {
      case front
      case back
  }
  var activeCam: cameraFacing = .back
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Configure ARKit Session
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
    self.activeCam = .back // set the active camera
    // Reverse camera button
    if ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {
      // add reverse camera button
      let reverseCameraBtn = UIButton()
      reverseCameraBtn.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.maxX-75, y: 25, width: 50, height: 50)
      if let imageReverseCameraBtn = UIImage(named: "cameraFlip") {
          reverseCameraBtn.setImage(imageReverseCameraBtn, for: .normal)
      }
      self.view.insertSubview(reverseCameraBtn, at: 3)
      self.cameraFlipBtn = reverseCameraBtn
    }
    self.cameraFlipBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchCamera), for: .touchDown)
  }
  @objc private func switchCamera() {
    if self.activeCam == .back {
      // switch to front config
      let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
      configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
      // run the config to swap the camera
      self.sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
      self.activeCam = .front
    } else {
      // switch to back cam config
      let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
      configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
      // run the config to swap the camera
      self.sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
      self.activeCam = .back
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a good solution for a quick fix for a demo. Because ARFaceTrackingConfiguration is not supported on older devices(without TrueDepth camera) I will dig more into Agora

Comment: For devices that don't support front facing AR you can create a new view that uses Agora's SDK, could even use the UiKit https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/iOS-UIKit

Answer (score 0):

instead of enableVideo()/disableVideo() video, try:

```swift
self.agoraKit.enableLocalVideo(true/false)
```

Comment: Hi Max, doing this just stops/starts the local video, but this local video is still the same as what's coming from arVideoSource. And I noticed one thing - agoraKit.switchCamera() mirrors back and forward the outcome from customVideoSource. I'm starting to think that I need to implement one more customVideoSource that will just default camera outcome and switch these sources. Not sure if this will work, by the way